# How to make an array more efficient, by ignoring elements with 0 in them

Tags: c, arrays, factorial

I have a piece of code which calculates a large factorial,

The assignment states that i must use arrays, however it is incredibly inefficient as the range is from 20! to 60! so i have to use an array which has 82 elements as 60! is 82 digits long.

This means that when calculating the sum of the digits within 29! there will be lots of elements which contain a 0, but the code will multiply through them anyway.

Is there a way to overcome this? I was told about a malloc function? but i'm not too sure!

Comment: [malloc()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) is for allocating memory.

Comment: More efficient in terms of memory or in terms of time. Can you post your code?

Comment: I guess you need to calculate the factorial "by hand"? Then you need to do touch every digit anyway, so you can as well test for 0 before a multiplication step. Using "sparse vectors" (thats what the darastructures you describe are called) is probably beyond this assignment.

Comment: Also -- just in case you were overlooking it -- you don't *have* to use all 82 digits for every operation. If you have to add 10 to 8, you would not calculate it as "000010 + 000008".

Answer (score 0):

Malloc function is used to dinamically allocate memory. You may see this like an variable size array. But this is not useful in your case.

It is known that the number of 0s in the factorial product is equal with the number of divisors equal with 5 of all the numbers in the product (because 10 = 2*5 and there are more 2s than 5s). To be more clear, let's see an example:

10! = 1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10

If we factorize everything:

10! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 2^2 * 5 * 2*3 * 7 * 2^3 * 3^2 * 2*5 = 2^9 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 7

If you want to calculate the digits sum of 10!, you can get rid of 2 5s and 2 2s, and compute the product:

2^7 * 3^4 * 7

This will get rid of all 0s from your final product, but will take a little longer, as you have to do more computations.